# Como hacer redireccionamientos por ID o por Ruta que no existe en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Buenas tengo la siguientes dudas y no se como solventarlo, os detallo. Si tenemos al usuario que no esta logueado y por ejemplo la area de login es `http://127.0.0.1:80/login` si por ejemplo el usuario pone en la URL `http://127.0.0.1:80/login/lo_que_sea` o bien `http://127.0.0.1:80/lo_que_sea` da el siguiente mensaje en laravel "*Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.*" ¿Como deberia de controlar estas cosas?

Y la siguiente duda es, si el usuario ya esta Logueado correctamente y entra en el panel de administracion y desea editar una categoria por ejemplo el **ID 1** quedando asi la ruta `http://127.0.0.1:80/admin/edit/1` si por ejemplo el usuario toca por GET el **ID 1** y por ejemplo pone el **ID 1000** quedando asi la URL `http://127.0.0.1:80/admin/edit/1000`, evidentemente no tengo ningun registro con el **ID 1000**, por tanto me da el siguiente error `Trying to get property 'nombrePack' of non-object (View:...` ¿Como puedo realizar la comprobacion si existe o no el ID pasado por GET?

Comment: En ambos casos se debería de retornar un 404, no se que ves de malo en esto. Si es bueno personalizar la vista del 404 y añadir algún enlace para ayudar al usuario.

Comment: Buenas @Xerif, no veo nada malo. Si no que no se que debo de pasarle o que parámetros debo añadirle en laravel para que tire o bien un error 404 o directamente un redirect. Pero no se como debo de proceder correctamente para realizarlo. ¿Sabrías indicarme que pasos debo seguir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para una vista personalizada de error 404 (cuando la ruta no existe), puedes hacer como dice en la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/errors#custom-http-error-pages):

"Crea una vista `resources/views/errors/404.blade.php`. Este archivo se incluirá en todos los errores 404 generados por su aplicación."

Puedes modificarla a tu antojo para que muestre un mensaje y/o link a una ruta existente.

Para el caso de un request con una ID que no existe, el error que te daría no sería 404. Para este caso puedes usar `try {} catch {}` en el controlador (mira en la misma página de la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/errors)).
Por ej:

```
try {
    $model = Model::findOrFail($id)
} catch (\Exception $exception) {
    return redirect()->route('...')->with('error', 'Se produjo un error obteniendo el item.');
}

return view('...', [$model]);
```

Finalmente, si un usuario quiere ir al login, se supone que es porque no está logueado. Si utilizas el `middleware` de autenticación incorporado de Laravel, cuando quieres acceder a una ruta que requiere autenticación, automáticamente te redireccionará al login.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function() {
    // tus rutas que precisan autenticación
});
```

Comment: He solucionado la parte de los ID enviados. Pero me falta por resolver, el problema si el usuario no esta logueado. Por ejemplo mi panel de administracion no tiene frontend. Por tanto accedes directamente a la ruta `http://127.0.0.1:80/login`. pero claro... Cuando modificas por ejemplo `http://127.0.0.1:80/login_Loquesea` o `http://127.0.0.1:80/login/aquipongoloquesea` me tira el mensaje mencionado **Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found**. ¿Como lo soluciono? Y gracias por la ayuda Pablo.

Comment: @Fumatamax o prueba agregar a tu archivo de rutas 
 `Route::fallback(function () {    return redirect('login'); }); `

Comment: Puedes lanzar un error 404 con la función `abort();` de laravel, mandándole el código de error `HTTP`.